# Three separate forms inside the tab div

Tags: php, html

I have three reports inside the tab div.all these forms are submit forms and the data has to be saved into the database.all these forms work fine individually but when i give inside the tab div only the 1st form works fine but it will affect the functionality of other two and im not able to insert the values into the database.Is there anything that i need to know before placing these forms inside the tab.i need to solve this ASAP.please help!!!

this is my code: I have used include() to pass the control to that particular file onclicking the tab div.is that the right way?

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="ex.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="tab-links">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1"> Report1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2"> Report2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">Report3</a></li>
     </ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab active">

        <?php
        include("Report1.php");

         ?>

 </div>     
   <div id="tab2" class="tab">

        <?php
        include ("Report2.php");
         ?>


    </div>
     <div id="tab3" class="tab">
  <p>
        <?php
        include("Report3.php");
         ?>
         </p>

    </div>
     </div>
</div>  

    </body>
</html>
```

here is my jquery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
        var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');

        // Show/Hide Tabs
        jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

        // Change/remove current tab to active
        jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

here is my PHP file:Report1.php

```
 <?php
    include_once 'dataAccessControl.php';
    $DataAccessController = new DataAccessController();
    if(isset($_POST['report']))
     {
        $daydropdown=$_POST['daydropdown'];
        $monthdropdown=$_POST['monthdropdown'];
        $yeardropdown=$_POST['yeardropdown'];
        $dreport_place=$_POST['dreport_place'];
        $dreport_address=$_POST['dreport_address'];
        $dreport_additional=$_POST['dreport_additional'];
     }
     else 
     {
        $daydropdown="";
        $monthdropdown="";
        $yeardropdown="";
        $dreport_place ="";
        $dreport_address="";
        $dreport_additional="";
     }

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
    {
        $death = $DataAccessController->death_reports($_POST['daydropdown'],$_POST['monthdropdown'],$_POST['yeardropdown'],$_POST['dreport_place'], $_POST['dreport_address'], $_POST['dreport_additional']);
        if ($death) {
              echo"<p><font  color=red  size='5pt' > Your Death Report has been Registered</font></p>";
            header("Refresh:3;url='newhome.php'");
            } 
    }
    ?>

    <html>
    <head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title>Death Report</title>  

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var monthtext=['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sept','Oct','Nov','Dec'];

    function populatedropdown(dayfield, monthfield, yearfield)
    {
       var today=new Date()
       var dayfield=document.getElementById(dayfield)
       var monthfield=document.getElementById(monthfield)
       var yearfield=document.getElementById(yearfield)
        for (var i=0; i<=31; i++)
       dayfield.options[i-1]=new Option(i, i)
       dayfield.options[today.getDate()-1]=new Option(today.getDate(), today.getDate(), true, true) //select today's day
       for (var m=0; m<12; m++)
       monthfield.options[m]=new Option(monthtext[m], monthtext[m])
       monthfield.options[today.getMonth()]=new Option(monthtext[today.getMonth()], monthtext[today.getMonth()], true, true) //select today's month
       var thisyear=1999
       for (var y=0; y<45; y++){
       yearfield.options[y]=new Option(thisyear, thisyear)
       thisyear+=1
       }
       yearfield.options[0]=new Option(today.getFullYear(), today.getFullYear(), true, true) //select today's year
    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body >
    <div id="color" >
        <table>

                <h1 align="center"><p> Report1</h1>


        <form action="" method="POST">
            <tr><td>Date  </td><td>
                <select name="daydropdown" id="daydropdown"></select> 
                <select name="monthdropdown" id="monthdropdown"></select>
                <select name="yeardropdown" id="yeardropdown"></select>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                //populatedropdown(id_of_day_select, id_of_month_select, id_of_year_select)
                    window.onload=function()
                    {
                        populatedropdown("daydropdown", "monthdropdown", "yeardropdown")
                    }
                </script>
            </td></tr>

            <tr><td></br>  Place  </td><td></br><select name="dreport_place"id="wgtmsr">
            <option value="hospital" >Hospital</option><option value="residence">Residence</option><option value="others">Others</option></select></td></tr>

            <tr><td>Address  </td><td></br><textarea name="dreport_address" rows="5" cols="32" id="loc" value=""> </textarea></td></tr>

            <tr><td>Additional Cases if any</td><td></br> <textarea name="dreport_additional" rows="5" cols="32" id="loc" value=""> </textarea></td></tr></label></td></tr>

            <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" name="report" value="Save" id="btnsize" /></td></tr>

        </form>
        </table></br>
    </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: the problem is related to what you have in your php files. the script is working fine and has nothing to do with your problem. kindly include the code in php files.

Comment: i have included one php file..please see it.

Comment: you should remove those extra `<html>` and `<body>` tags in your php files in the first place. you already have 1 html and body tag in the first page you've provided. is that php file the one that's working?

Comment: all the 3 works fine individually.so wicheva is the 1st one in the tab that works.but the 2nd and 3rd one doesnt work.ya this works if i gv it in the first tab.

Comment: I suppose all Report.php files have the same condition to submit form: `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"`. Am I right?

Comment: yes its same @Giorgio

Comment: how can i make the tab to stay on the current tab after pressing the submit button.can u plzzz help me?@Ozgur Bar @Giorgio

Answer (score 1):

Look what you're doing here:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
{
    $death = $DataAccessController->death_reports($_POST['daydropdown'],$_POST['monthdropdown'],$_POST['yeardropdown'],$_POST['dreport_place'], $_POST['dreport_address'], $_POST['dreport_additional']);
    if ($death) {
          echo"<p><font  color=red  size='5pt' > Your Death Report has been Registered</font></p>";
        header("Refresh:3;url='newhome.php'");
        } 
}
```

This is from Report1.php and is included before Report2.php and Report3.php.

When you post one of these 3 forms, the condition below is met

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
```

and you make a redirection using

```
header("Refresh:3;url='newhome.php'");
```

The rest of the code is never executed.

**EDIT**

You still have the following block in the code

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
  //Move_Me
}
```

Wrap the code `Move_Me` in

```
if(isset($_POST['report']))
{
  //MoveD_Me
}
```

and remove

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
```

block.

Comment: i have included all the insertion query in one file.so only if the insertion is successfull then it goes to newhome.php.

Comment: i did the same as u said...but still its the same :(

Comment: are you using the same `name` value for all submit buttons? how do you handle each form on server side?

Comment: okay, and if you've updated all three php files accordingly this should work. you have removed `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")` block from all three of them, right? and wrapped the db logic in `if(isset($_POST['report']))` for Report1.php, `if(isset($_POST['report2']))` for Report2.php and `if(isset($_POST['report3']))` for Report3.php?

Comment: can't progress any further without seeing the most recent code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is all forms have the same submit condition

```
$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"
```

Assign a unique name to submit buttons, like this

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" name="btnsize1" />
```

And then change your submit condition to

```
if(isset($_POST['btnsize1']))
```

This will submit only the desired form. Of course, you need to update the first section (where you initialize variables from `$_POST` values) from

```
if(isset($_POST['report']))
```

to

```
if(isset($_POST['btnsize1']))
```

Comment: Are still forms all submitted at the same time?

Comment: it gives error while submitting. 'undefined index'.

Comment: Ooh!! Yep!! My mistake... You should use `name` instead of `id` on submit button properties. I've updated the code on submit button. I've also added a correction on first submit section. Try it now!

Comment: @jermina: have you tried the last updated code? Could you please give some feedback?

Comment: yeah...i used exit in my inserting query function so inserting works now but problem with other things like date not displaying..:(